# Previously working Python program reports in IndentationError when new variables are added

Tags: python, bash, python-2.7, indentation, atom-editor

I'm getting "Indentation Error: Unexpected indent" in places I don't think I should be getting them in.

Here is my code for reference, along with a detailed explanation below:

```
for PID in PID_book:
    print "\n##############################\nTEXT!\n##############################\n"
    ### COMMENT ###
    print "\n##### AND MORE TEXT #####\n"
    # Iterate through the lines and add valid data to the lists
    gap_count = 0
    hr_temp_total = 0
    same_hr_count = 0
    cur_dt = time.time()
    first_run = True
    # Keep track of the month for cool-looking progress bar
    cur_month = 0
```

Above gap_count and cur_month are new variables I added. I get an indentation error at the the line with gap_count. If I remove that line, I still get the same error at the declaration of cur_month. So it seems like these new variables are causing problems which I don't understand because these issues don't occur with the older variables and I've entered them the same way with the same IDE.

I've removed all empty lines, and I've double checked to ensure this is LF newlines not CRLF.

This is python 2.7 running in a bash shell on CentOS. I am using ATOM to edit.

Comment: Are you mixing tabs and spaces for indentation?

Comment: No, I use tabs only.

Comment: But is your editor automatically converting tabs to spaces? If there's a mismatch between editors then you can still get this.

Comment: There is one tab in front of `gap_count = 0` and another line, spaces in front of the others. You can see it if you try to edit your post and select the space in front of the line. So, you definitely have a mix of spaces and tabs. Use only spaces to avoid problems!

Comment: This is not about your error, but the loop here doesn't really do anything. Is that really your loop that is giving the error or just something similar? Can you copy paste exactly from your editor? And also please provide some lines before the loop

Answer (score 0):

I've been struggling with the same error. I have properly indented django/python code. When I run `python manage.py shell < my_script.py` in bash, I get an `IndentationError`. The issue was because I used CRLF line endings (Windows). I switched to LF (Unix) and it solved the problem.

In the Atom editor you can toggle between the two using the menu at the bottom right (on mine it's the first item in the menu). Still looking for it in Sublime...

Comment: I am fairly confident that this could not possibly have been what actually solved the problem; but I am asking on the Python discourse forum to make sure: https://discuss.python.org/t/did-python-ever-care-about-line-endings-in-source-code/41598 In all likelihood, your code appeared properly indented due to your editor's tab-stop settings, but used mixed tabs and spaces in a way that Python rejects.